# Problem relating to FSM machine

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am trying to write a verilog code for a Fibonacci sequence generator. It's output will be nth Fibonacci number where n is the output of the count. The code works for count = 2. But when the count increases, all the specified register values goes to 0. I am suspecting the error might be in the always block that contains the case statement. How can I solve the problem?

```
module fib(clk, reset, count, out, prev,present, temp);
// This module generates nth fibonacchi number, where n is the output of the count
    input clk, reset;
    output reg[7:0] count;
    output [7:0]out;
    output reg [7:0]prev, present, temp;
    //state register
    always @(posedge clk)
        if(reset==1) count = 1;
        else count = count + 1;

    //next state logic
    always @(count[0])
    case(count)
    8'b00000001:begin
                prev = 8'bxxxxxxxx; present = 8'bxxxxxxxx;
                end
    8'b00000010:begin
                prev = 8'b00000000; present = 8'b00000001;
                end
    default: begin
                temp = present;
                present = present + prev;
                prev = temp;
            end
    endcase

    //output logic

    assign out = present;

endmodule
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80400/discussion-on-question-by-user308177-problem-relating-to-fsm-machine).

Answer (score 3):

You are writing Verilog as if it is a standard programming language. HDL languages work rather different.

1. In your count section use non-blocking assignments.
2. In your always section you are generating latches. The whole 'always' section should be controlled by a clock as you have 'memory' elements in there: You want the values of prev, temp and present to be 'remembered'.
3. It is common (good) practice to always use begin-end sections.
   In your case it works because you have a single statement (`if` and `case`).
4. The Fibonacci sequence starts with 1,1 which is not in your code.
5. If you use non-blocking assignments, you no longer need the 'temp' variable:

```
prev    <= present
present <= present + prev;
```

Side notes:

1. A name like 'out' is not very descriptive. Even if you write short test snippets use descriptive names.
2. It is bad practice to use always @( variable ) these days. It can lead to simulation synthesis mismatches. You should use `always @( * )` or alway_comb.
3. Comment as at the bottom of your example is rather superfluous:

```
//output logic   
assign out = present;
```

Comment: `begin`/`end` isn't needed if there's only one statement in a block. Stylistically I'd rather see it than check carefully whether it's needed, but I don't think this is what's causing OP's unexplained behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Finally the code has run somewhat perfectly after I initialized used posedge clk for both always block. Could you comment on why combinational assignment didn't work here? The pastebin link for the code is given:
https://pastebin.com/jmC6aw1L

Comment: @ThePhoton : Yes I noticed, I will update. @user308177: You made some weird combinatorial loop with latches. HDL is like *hardware*. If you write e.g. a=b+1; b=a; you make a 'circuit' where the output goes straight back into the input. The `@(posedge clk)`breaks the loop with a register.